# Mysql multiple joins, duplicated data returned

Tags: mysql, inner-join

My table structure:

```
Lantern
Lantern_type
Location
Loan
Borrower
```

My query returns duplicates, I am looking for a solution which does not include repeated data.

**Code**

```
SELECT
    l.lantern_id, l.lantern_name, l.lantern_state,lt.lantern_type,
    lt.lantern_type_description, lt.lantern_type_tech_info, 
    lt.lantern_type_lens, lo.location_id, lo.location_name, loa.loan_id, 
    loa.loan_start_date, loa.loan_end_date, b.borrower_id, b.borrower_name, b.user_id
FROM lantern as l
INNER JOIN lantern_type as lt
    ON l.lantern_id = lt.lantern_type_id
INNER JOIN location as lo
    ON lt.LANTERN_TYPE_ID = l.lantern_id
INNER JOIN loan as loa
    ON lo.LOCATION_ID = loa.LOAN_ID
INNER JOIN borrower as b
    ON loa.loan_id = b.borrower_id
;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
select l.lantern_id, l.lantern_name, l.lantern_state,lt.lantern_type,
    lt.lantern_type_description, lt.lantern_type_tech_info, 
    lt.lantern_type_lens, lo.location_id, lo.location_name, loa.loan_id, 
    loa.loan_start_date, loa.loan_end_date, b.borrower_id, b.borrower_name, b.user_id
From lantern as l
INNER JOIN lantern_type as lt ON
    l.lantern_id = lt.lantern_type_id
INNER JOIN location as lo ON
    lt.LANTERN_TYPE_ID = l.lantern_id
INNER JOIN loan as loa ON 
    lo.LOCATION_ID = loa.LOAN_ID
INNER JOIN borrower as b ON
    loa.loan_id = b.borrower_id
GROUP BY l.lantern_id;
```

See [MySql GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and probably not relevant to your case now but I cannot agree with the accepted answer.  In this case the accepted answer is just masking the problem.

From looking at your join statements your issue was probably with this join:

```
INNER JOIN location as lo
    ON lt.LANTERN_TYPE_ID = l.lantern_id
```

You don't use the correct table alias on this join. I suspect the alias after the `=` should have been `lo` instead of `l`.

Comment: Oh yes, I can see what you mean. But I cannot recall correctly at this time as the problem occurred a while ago. But I can see that the join is incorrect. +1 for the answer.